# Why are security settings blocking this java applet?

Tags: java, html, css, security

So I am trying to have a scrolling ticker  like the news has and I found an applet but there are two problems.
1. Security settings are blocking it
2. I don't understand how the codebase works to look at the java source code.

If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

```
  <APPLET NAME="Ticker1"
        CODE="Ticker.class"
        ARCHIVE="Ticker.jar"
        CODEBASE="http://java.barchart.com/ticker"
        HEIGHT="40"
        WIDTH="450"
    >

        <PARAM NAME="panels"    VALUE="1">
        <PARAM NAME="1:symbols" VALUE="'Indices,$NASX:Nasdaq Comp,'Stocks,IBM,GE,EBAY,YHOO:Yahoo!">
        <PARAM NAME="1:scroll"    VALUE="-1, 50">
        <PARAM NAME="1:bgcolor"   VALUE="#000000">
        <PARAM NAME="1:fgcolor"   VALUE="#FFFFFF">
        <PARAM NAME="1:pscolor"   VALUE="#00CC00">
        <PARAM NAME="1:ngcolor"   VALUE="#FF3333">
        <PARAM NAME="1:hilight"   VALUE="#FFFF00">
        <PARAM NAME="1:font"      VALUE="Arial, Bold, 12">
        <PARAM NAME="1:multiline" VALUE="true">
    </APPLET>
```

Here is the webmaster tool http://www.insidestocks.com/ticker.asp

Comment: Is the applet signed?

Comment: I can't tell because I don't know how to get to the actual jar file using the codebase/archive/code

Comment: Have you installed the least jre version? Firefox will block too old java plugins